# Rails Test Unit: How to find an unused id for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

When testing a model with a foreign key, I'd like to assert the model can't be saved with an inexistent foreign key.

*Example class for testing:*

```
class Wheel
    belongs_to: car
end
```

So, a unit test would look like this:

```
def test "a wheel must belong to an existent car"
    @wheel = Wheel.new
    @wheel.car_id = INEXISTENT_CAR_ID
    assert !@wheel.save
end
```

What is the best way to find a valid INEXISTENT_CAR_ID (knowing fixtures are loaded with random ids)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Chowlett's approach. But it fails, if there is no record at all, so you might want to write

```
@wheel.car_id = Car.order("id").last.try(:id).to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's an easier way, but you could go for:

```
@wheel.car_id = Car.find(:last, :order => :id).id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to arrange it so that your fixture or your mock actually has ids you can control. Say if you were using factorygirl, you can say:

```
 @car1 = Factory(:car, :id => 1) 
 @car2 = Factory(:car, :id => 2)
```

so you are sure that in your test db you only have 2 ids, 1 and 2. That way you can set up that given a Wheel with an id of 3, then it should not save.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer using only the rails test framework.